# How to test the value of a function which is access using instance() method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component like bellow

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { ActionWrapper } from 'components/Wrappers'

import { P } from 'components/Text'

class TestStock extends Component {
  total = (a, b) => {
    let totValue = 0
    totValue = a + b
    return totValue
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ActionWrapper
        title="In stock"
        description={'Manage your in stock items'}
      >
        <P>Total is {this.totValue}</P>
      </ActionWrapper>
    )
  }
}

export default TestStock
```

and i have write a test ,  to test the total function bellow

```
 describe('total function in the stock', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Stock />)
  const value = wrapper.instance().total(5 + 7)

  test('for total value calculation', () => {
    expect(value).toBe(6)
  })

  test('for total less or equal to 10 ', () => {
    expect(value).toBeLessThanOrEqual(10)
  })
})
```

But the test failed as i received the Nan as the value. 
What i have done wrong , how can i test this function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that instead of passing the values as arguments to the instance function, you pass then as an expression and hence the second argument is `undefined` which results in `a + b` to be evaluated to `NaN` inside the function. Change your code to

```
const value = wrapper.instance().total(5, 7)
```